# changing server time to IST

Tags: linux, tomcat, liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6

I have a jsp in two different server, one having liferay 5 and tomcat 6, the other has liferay 6 and tomcat 7
    <%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
    
    
     <%
    Date date = new Date();
    %>
   Date: <%=date %>
 
   Offset: <%=date.getTimezoneOffset() %>

In liferay 5 server the date is coming in IST but in liferay 6 it is coming in GMT, What should I change to bring it to IST. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use portal-ext.properties and add

```
#
# This sets the default time zone of the portal.
#
company.default.time.zone=UTC
```

Or go to ControlPanel, Portal Section, "Portal Settings", "Display Settings" and set the server's timezone there.

You typically want to set the timezone to the same timezone your server is configured to run in (check the OS for this). Which server you need to change depends on which one actually is configured correctly currently.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I soved by changing the time zone in liferay settings.

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheived by setting up jvm param in start up script as below 
   set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Duser.timezone=IST